# Edit WP payment plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to edit a payment plugin for Wordpress. The plugin that I´m using for my site is Photo Seller Plugin (https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/wordpress-photo-seller-plugin), but I want to change the checkout site, because this is too old. So I was thinking in implement that plugin but using from checkout another payment plug in.

It´s this possible, can I change the checkout part editing the PHP files? I took a look at the files and both of them have many folders and files. I want to know if someone has done this before to give me some light in the problem.

I have been seeing that has many folders dedicated for the checkout, and I should change all the variables and make it one, so I don´t know by where I can start.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can I use one part of a plugin inside another plugin? I want to use from checkout option of one in another payment plugin